# Is there any way using we can call a timed function using C? ie we will wait for function return for a specified amount of time

Tags: c, timer, operating-system, embedded, sys

Is there any way using we can call a timed function using C? that is we will wait for function return for a specified amount of time.

Comment: It is not possible in standard C. You have to use system-specific functions for this. And since you don't mention which system you are using, this question is too broad to answer.

Comment: @Lundin Im using linux system. Is it possible using system programming? If so please provide a solution for this.

Comment: Then you can use pthreads for this.

Answer (score 0):

C itself doesn't directly do this, so there are multiple ways to address such a need.

**Give the function itself a sense of time**.   This is typically the best first-line part of a solution, because it is the function itself which is in a position to gracefully fail if it is taking too long. Any loop would check the elapsed time.  Typically where things actually get "stuck" are in blocking system calls, so you would want to use versions of these which have timeouts, use non-blocking versions with your own concatenation to partial buffers, or make them contingent on mechanisms such as select() or poll()

**Use another thread** to watch the time.  The issue here, is what happens to the thread where a call is taking too long?  Methods to terminate a thread are *awkward* and sometimes not even implemented in simpler embedded Linuxes.  This may mean that instead of actually stopping the thread, you set a flag telling it you are no longer interested in its results, and it should return at the first (later) opportunity.  In short, apart from cases such as a pool of worker threads yielding asynchronous results, using threads isn't as clean a solution as it might at first appear, because the "and what if it takes too long?" situation is inelegant.

**Use a supervisory thread or daemon to monitor the entire process**.   This *is* a fairly commonly solution, because in the case of failure you can kill and restart the entire process - a process *is* what operating systems are engineered to treat as a moderately independent unit of software state, so restarting an entire one is much cleaner than trying to force terminate and restart a part of one.

**Put a watchdog on the entire system**.  A watchdog is a hardware or (kernel-level) software timer which will trigger a reboot if it is not "serviced" at regular intervals - typically because the tasks that is supposed to do the servicing either blocks or unexpectedly exits.   Because forced restarts can lead to corruption of filesystem state, this is typically best used as a last resort that will activate only when loop- or process- level timeouts fail to protect against a blocked situation.; often this is there to catch *unanticipated* failure modes while those less drastic methods catch anticipated ones at the source.  Also note that if you run a watchdog from a user mode program, you'll need to safe the watchdog if you manually stop that program for maintenance; you typically *do not* want a program to stop the watchdog on its own exit, unless you are sure that only happens in a code path where it is desired to have the program stop.

---

If at all possible, use the first method of making the function itself time limited, then consider wrapping it for safety in a process- or system- level monitoring for fallback.